# Old phone wire or cat5,

Tags: dsl

I no longer have a home phone and only use it for DSL. AT&T came out and repaired outside lines and said I needed to replace old phone lines. I only have one left and that's to the router. The tech said they replace it with cat5. I figured I could save myself a little money by doing it. After reading some if that's right. Is cat5 or cat6 the way to go from box to router?

Comment: Cat 5e will do just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend Cat5e. It will still offer gigabit speeds, while saving money. If you really feel the need to plan for a 10 gigabit network and the future, you can go with cat6, but, you have DSL coming in and that is pretty far off.

Comment: But this isn't for Ethernet, as I understood it – it's for the phone line, where even something like Cat3 seems enough?

Comment: @grawity You are correct. At the least, I suppose cat3 will work just fine as well. He just asked about 5 or 6 and 3 didn't even cross my mind. In the future, cat3 may limit the bandwidth as it's max throughput is 16mbps. Also, there is much more susceptibility to interference using cat3. But, it will most likely work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Cat 3 is technically sufficient for this. If you don't have any cable, I'd recommend buying cat 5e cable because the price is reasonable and you can also use it for Ethernet wiring up to gigabit speeds. If you happen to have cat 6 cable, of course, you can use it.